# Estilizar a combo box do select do Bootstrap 4

Tags: select, combobox

é possível estilizar a combo box do boostrap 4 ?

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control pesquisa__select col-12">
         <option>teste 01</option>
          <option>teste 02</option>
          <option>teste 03</option>
       </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sim, é possível, o que pretendes fazer?

Comment: Gostaria de tirar a bordar azul da combo box, deixar mais arrendondo os cantos, deixar mais bonito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível realizar essa alteração estilizando o próprio elemento, no exemplo a baixo usei um `class=selectCustom` e fiz todas as minhas alterações para essa classe.

> Em suas chamadas de arquivo, o arquivo de estilização deve ser chamado após o arquivo do bootstrap na tag head.

```css
select.selectCustom:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: 0;
}
select.selectCustom{
  border-radius: 30px !important
}
select.selectCustom option{
  color: #ff0;
  background-color: #f00
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control pesquisa__select col-12 selectCustom">
    <option>teste 01</option>
    <option>teste 02</option>
    <option>teste 03</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Então..eu quero estilizar a combo box que abre, dos options.

Comment: Entendi, não foi muito claro na pergunta, as opções do elemento `select`, só é possível alterar o `background` e `color`, como no código a cima, caso queria realizar mais estilização, é possível criar seu próprio `select`, como alguns plugins já usam, como o `select2`

Comment: Realmente não fui muito assertivo na pergunta, vou verificar esse plugin. Agradeço a ajuda !

Answer (score -2):

você criando os seletores customizados é possível sim estilizar conforme sua necessidade.

De uma revisada nesta lista, talvez possa lhe ajudar melhor a entender mais seletores e qual sua funcionalidade:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp